# How to add jquery UI spinner on jqgrid table column

Tags: jquery, cakephp, spinner, jqgrid-php

Is it possible to add jQuery UI spinner on jqgrid table column ?

I have a jqgrid table with more than 7000+ records, I am want to apply spinner on one column. Does jqgrid allow to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A spinner that allows for inline updating?

Comment: Please provide simple jsfiddle example that uses jqgrid.

Comment: Hm, are you seriously willing to present a table with 7000 'editable' rows on a single page? That's a lot of rows. Even if it will work, browsers will not be very happy with that and performance will have a serious impact

Comment: @thaJeztah I am displaying 50 records at time, not 7000 records at once

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are a number of ways.

You can either pass the html as the cell data, so instead of just a number pass something like (not the best way):

```
<input class="spinner" name="value">
```

after the grid has loaded use:

```
your_jqgrid.gridComplete(function(){$(".spinner")..spinner();
```

Better yet, you could also set up a formatter for the column and do everything in one go there.